# HTTParty Patch Sinatra API returns "invalid value"

Tags: ruby, sinatra

The following route works as far as reaching out to the api.

The api returns "invalid value". I'd assume this is a data type issue. 
API docs:

```
value
  string    
Value of the zone setting
  "off"
default value: off
valid values: on, off
```

API CURL example:

```
curl -X PATCH "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/settings/development_mode" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"value":"off"}'
```

Route:

```
    get '/devModeOff' do
          headers = {
            "X-Auth-Email" => '####',
            "X-Auth-Key" =>   '####',
            "Content-Type" => 'application/json'
          }
   options = '{value: 'off'}'

         @result = HTTParty.patch(
          'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/####/settings/development_mode',
          :headers => headers,
          :data => options
          )
          puts @result

          redirect to ('/')
        end
```

Being very new to ruby, how would I fix this?

Comment: Do you actually have `null` in your code, or did you just redact those values when you wrote your question? If the latter, you should make a note of that in the question (and perhaps use something more obvious than `null`, e.g. `######`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Route" code isn't valid Ruby code, so I'm not sure how it's running at all. In particular, this line has unclosed quotation marks:

```
options = '{value: 'off'}'
```

I'm not sure what you were intending to do here—if you were trying to make a Ruby Hash or a JSON string—but what you want to do is this:

```
headers = {
  "X-Auth-Email" => "####",
  "X-Auth-Key"   => "####",
  "Content-Type" => "application/json"
}

options = { value: "off" }

@result = HTTParty.patch(
  "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/####/settings/development_mode",
  headers: headers,
  body: options.to_json
)
```

Note that `options` is a Hash, and it's given to `HTTParty.patch` as the `:body` option (not `:data`).

Comment: This renders invalid headers. The headers worked before this. If I turn `headers => headers` into `:headers => headers` it works and we are back to invalid value again. Thank you for any additional help

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "invalid headers," but my code doesn't say `headers => headers`. It says `headers: headers`, which in all versions of Ruby since 1.9.3 is equivalent to `:headers => headers`.

Comment: The API responds with Malformed JSON in request body. Go easy on me lol. First ruby app. I'm a node.js guy.

Comment: If you add `debug_output: $stdout` (or `:debug_output => $stdout`) to the arguments, what does it print?

Comment: `starting SSL for api.cloudflare.com:443...
SSL established
<- "PATCH /client/v4/zones//settings/development_mode HTTP/1.1\r\nX-Auth-Email:\r\nX-Auth-Key: a\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: api.cloudflare.com\r\nContent-Length: 9\r\n\r\n"
<- "value=off"1`

Comment: Ah. I had thought HTTParty would automatically JSON-encode the `:body`, but it doesn't. `to_json` should fix that; I've updated my answer.